# Python: Linklist deque addfront & addrear

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and now I'm having a problem in this program.

First here's the NodeList: <-linklist

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext
```

And here's my program:

```
from NodeList import Node
class DequeLL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.last = None
        self.length = 0

    def addFrontDLL(self, item):
        temp = Node(str(item))
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp
        length = max(len(node.data) for node in self.allNodes()) if self.head else 0
        print('\u2510{}\u250c'.format(' '*length))
        for node in self.allNodes():
            print('\u2502{:<{}}\u2502'.format(node.data, length))
        print('\u2514{}\u2518'.format('\u2500'*length))

    def addRearDLL(self, item):
        node = Node(str(item))
        node.next = None
        if self.length == 0:
            self.head = self.last = node
        else:
            last = self.last
            last.next = node
            self.last = node
        self.length = self.length + 1 
        length = max(len(node.data) for node in self.allNodes()) if self.head else 0
        print('\u2510{}\u250c'.format(' '*length))
        for node in self.allNodes():
            print('\u2502{:<{}}\u2502'.format(node.data, length))
        print('\u2514{}\u2518'.format('\u2500'*length))

    def allNodes(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next

d = DequeLL()
```

Everything was fine when I add an item in addFrontDLL. But after adding an item in addRearDLL, its like the item is added on another container. Then I tried to add using addFrontDLL again and it works of how I want it (the item is added on that another container). See the picture below:

[image]

I hope someone explain and fix it for me. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set the `DequeLL.last` field when adding a node with `addFrontDLL` at the front for the first time. Your `addRearDLL` does properly handle adding new nodes, which is why everything works after adding at the rear.

Try this:

```
class DequeLL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.last = None
        self.length = 0

    def __str__(self): # Refactored for clarity
        width = (max(len(node.data) for node in self.allNodes()) 
                    if self.head else 0) # width to avoid ambiguity with self.length
        s = ['\u2510{}\u250c'.format(' '*width)]
        for node in self.allNodes():
            s.append('\u2502{:<{}}\u2502'.format(node.data, width))
        s.append('\u2514{}\u2518'.format('\u2500'*width))
        return '\n'.join(s)

    def addFrontDLL(self, item):
        temp = Node(str(item))
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp
        if self.last is None: # if adding to an empty deque, set the last node, too
            self.last = temp
        self.length += 1
        print(self) # refactored the pretty-printing into __str__ for clarity

    def addRearDLL(self, item):
        node = Node(str(item))
        node.next = None
        if self.length == 0:
            self.head = self.last = node
        else:
            last = self.last
            last.next = node
            self.last = node
        self.length = self.length + 1 
        print(self)

    def allNodes(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next
```

The output of your example is now:

```
In [97]: d = DequeLL()

In [98]: d.addFrontDLL('circle')
┐      ┌
│circle│
└──────┘

In [99]: d.addFrontDLL('arc')
┐      ┌
│arc   │
│circle│
└──────┘

In [100]: d.addRearDLL('123')
┐      ┌
│arc   │
│circle│
│123   │
└──────┘

In [101]: d.addFrontDLL('arc')
┐      ┌
│arc   │
│arc   │
│circle│
│123   │
└──────┘

In [102]: d.addFrontDLL('circle')
┐      ┌
│circle│
│arc   │
│arc   │
│circle│
│123   │
└──────┘

In [103]: d.addRearDLL('123')
┐      ┌
│circle│
│arc   │
│arc   │
│circle│
│123   │
│123   │
└──────┘
```